# Does RMAN in Oracle only copy the archive logs? What happens to the active redo log in case of failure?

Tags: backup, oracle-11g-r2, rman

If RMAN copy copies the archived redo logs when they are full, what happens to the current redo log in the event of a failure (hardware failure, etc.)?  Isn't there always an active redo log that is not an archive_log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the database is open in read-write mode there is always a number of changes to database that reside only in the current redo log and not in any archived log. If you want protect the current redo against hardware-related corruption, you need to add redundant storage (with either a remote replication or local mirror). If you want to protect the current redo from OS-related corruption, you need a "physical standby" database (the marketing term is DataGuard) with "SYNC LGWR" feed.

RMAN would not be useful to you, it is not designed for a a rolling backup of current redo.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing RMAN does it automatically perform an `ALTER SYSTEM ARCHIVE LOG CURRENT` to switch logfiles so that the active log at the point the backup was started will be included.

It doesn't do this in all backup situations, but this answers your question.